# NUnit Test with WatiN, runs OK from Dev10, but when NUnit started from "C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.5\bin\net-2.0\nunit.exe"

Tags: nunit, watin, comexception, specflow

I have the following code in an Nunit test ...

```
    string url = "";
    url = @"http://localhost/ClientPortalDev/Account/LogOn";
    ieStaticInstanceHelper = new IEStaticInstanceHelper();
    ieStaticInstanceHelper.IE = new IE(url);
    ieStaticInstanceHelper.IE.TextField(Find.ById("UserName")).TypeText("abc");
    ieStaticInstanceHelper.IE.TextField(Find.ById("Password")).TypeText("defg");
    ieStaticInstanceHelper.IE.Button(Find.ById("submit")).Click();
    ieStaticInstanceHelper.IE.Close();
```

On right-clicking the project in Dev10(visual studio 10) and choosing [Test With][NUnit 2.5], this test code runs with no problems. I have TestDriven installed.
  When opening the NUnit from C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.5\bin\net-2.0\nunit.exe" and then opening my test dll, the following text is reported in NUnit Errors and failures

```
... LoginAsWellKnownUserShouldSucceed:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

As an Aside ... Right-Clicking the source cs file in Dev10 and choosing Run Test, ... works as well. 
  The above test is actually part of TechTalk.SpecFlow 1.3 step, I have NUnit 2.5.5.10112,  installed, I have Watin 20.20 installed, 
  I have the following App.config for my test dll
  the start angle brackets have been removed ... how do you get xml to show up in

```
configuration>
  configSections>
    sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    /sectionGroup>
  /configSections>
  NUnit>
    TestRunner>
      add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
    /TestRunner>
  /NUnit>
  appSettings>
    add key="configCheck" value="12345" />
  /appSettings>
/configuration>
```

Anyone hit this before ?
The NUnit test obviously runs in NUnit 2.5.5 of TestDriven but not when running NUnit 2.5.5 from outside of Dev10 and TestDriven ?

Comment: Dev10=VisualStudio10 ; I am still working thru this one ; TestDriven uses nunit-x86 rather than nunit.exe; also played with removing all IE addins ; also played with getting IE for watin which i think is the real issue - it is very ... unreliable ... onwards ...

Answer (score 1):

Run the test in NUnit as admin.
I was running Dev10 as admin so I could attatch and debug w3ww, which was why the TestDriven test was working. 
As soon as I started running NUnit as admin the COM Server isue issue goess away.
What makes it more confusing is that running the hello-world exmaple against google from the Watin site works even though NUnit is not run as admin.
To use NUNit + Watin + against local web server, running NUnit as admin solves the com server exception issue.

Comment: +1 running as administrator worked for me too when automating IE as part of my NUnit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [RequiresSTA](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=requiresSTA&r=2.5) attribute in your test code instead of the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I am using MSTest, call Refresh to avoid cached data, this worked for me:

```
browser.Refresh();
browser.TextField(Find.ById("username")).TypeText("user");
browser.TextField(Find.ById("password")).TypeText("pass");
browser.Button(Find.ByName("SUBMIT")).Click();
```